# Reverse proxy with location directive

Tags: reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy which needs to redirect traffic to backend servers based on location directive. For example:

```
    https://rproxy.example.com/fileserver points to https://fileserver.example.com  


    https://rproxy.example.com/mail points to https://mail.example.com
```

I am open to using nginx or apache as reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Apache conf file and set something like the following..

```
    ProxyPass /fileserver/ http://fileserver.com:8080/fileserver/
    ProxyPassReverse /fileserver/ http://fileserver:8080/fileserver/

    ProxyPass /mailserver http://mailserver.com:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse /mailserver http://mailserver.com:8090/
```